# How to switch HTML text based on markup?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Here is my scenario, in the CMS I am using, I have created an Event module and I have two types of events, 'Conference' events and 'Training Course' events. On my event pagaes, I am using a [jQuery tabular system](http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/google-play-minimal-tabs-with-css3-jquery-demo.html) to show the content of my events. Below shows how my tabs markup look like:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab1">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab2">Agenda</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab3">Registration Fees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab4">Venue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab5">Sponsors</a></li>
</ul>
```

The tabs above suits well for my 'Conference' events but for my 'Training Course' events I want to show different tabs. For my 'Training Course' events I want to show the tabs below:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab1">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab2">Objectives</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab3">Faculty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab4">Registration Fees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab5">Education</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my events markup, I can pull and display the event type. This is how my markup looks like when the event type is Conference:

```
<div class="EventType">
    <ul class="sfCategoriesList">
        <li>
            <span id="taxonName">Conference</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is how the markup will look like if the event type is Training Course:

```
<div class="EventType">
    <ul class="sfCategoriesList">
        <li>
            <span id="taxonName">Training Course</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, is there a way to switch (change) the tabs text by identifying the event type by looking at the markup with jQuery?

I don't know how exactly to write the code but something like this logic:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab1">if the event type in the markup is "Training Course" then this tab text is "Description"</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab2">if the event type in the markup is "Training Course" then this tab text is "Objectives"</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var event = $('#taxonName').text();
if (event === 'Training Course') {
  $('#tab1').text('Description');
  $('#tab2').text('Objectives');
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm (with some tweaks).. thank you beautifulcoder thank you @Murali. This is what I did: 
var eventType = $('#taxonName').text();
        if (eventType === 'Training Course') {
            $('ul#tabs li:nth-child(1) a').text('Description');
            $('ul#tabs li:nth-child(2) a').text('Objectives');
            $('ul#tabs li:nth-child(3) a').text('Registration Fees');
            $('ul#tabs li:nth-child(4) a').text('Faculty');
            $('ul#tabs li:nth-child(5) a').text('Education');
        }